# Adobe Acrobat: How to disable navigation pop-up bar

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Is it possible to disable the navigation bar that pops up when you hover with your mouse over the bottom middle part of a .pdf file on Adobe Acrobat Pro DC on OSX (latest version installed as of today)?

Screenshot of the toolbar: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, click on the icon to the right of the pop up (the one with the arrow). That fixes the navigation to the tool bar on the top.